# calculating ratios in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to calculate the ratio of the total number of recommendations to the total number of reviews.

```
select     (count(recommendations.RecommendationId) / count(reservations.UserName) )
from  recommendations , reservations;
```

The output I am getting is 1.000, [there are 8 recommendations and 9 reservations in data]

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries:

```
select (select count(*) from recommendations) / (select count(*) from reservations);
```

Your query is generating a Cartesian product.  Then each count is counting the number of rows generating.  That count is the same, when you count non-`NULL` columns, so the ratio is `1`.